# bearded dragon perches when he sleeps why is that?

Tags: behavior, reptiles, bearded-dragon

My bearded dragon doesn't use his hiding spot. He rather prefers to perch on his basking spot to sleep. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It's his preferred sleeping spot, my dragon rotates between inside his cave and on top. Where they feel the warmest is where they will usually sleep or sometimes they're too lazy to switch spots :)

Comment: He may feel safer "on a branch" than he does "on the ground". That would make sense in the wild, I think.

Comment: He might! In the wild they do spend time in bushes/trees.

Answer (score 1):

My bearded dragon has always been the same way. From what I have gathered it is because they like to be up by the lights. In some cases if there is more than one in a cage (which shouldn't be the case, and I am not promoting. It can cause serious damage and even death) they will even lay on top of each other to get closer to the lights. So it is perfectly normal and you have nothing to worry about. Its just your little guy getting comfy!